# how to get Twitter profile info from FirebaseUI authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth, firebaseui

Currently i can get `DisplayName`, `Email` and `uid` etc, how to get handle name ex `@myname` and others like `description`.

**startActivityForResult:**

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build()


            );

            startActivityForResult(

                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),1
            );
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (response.isNewUser())
                {
                   String username = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                   String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                }

                Intent timelineIntent = new Intent(this, TimelineActivity.class);

                startActivity(timelineIntent);
                finish();

            } else {

                if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.PROVIDER_ERROR)
                    finish();

                if (response == null)
                    finish();
            }
        }
    }
```